# visual studio 2013, Error Code MSB4175

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed visual studios version 2013 update 4 on Windows 7, 64 bit system and tried building a project. In the process I am getting following error -

> FilesError    1   error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could
>   not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll". Could not
>   find file 'C:\Users\pratyush\AppData\Local\Temp\wuknqfms.dll'.

Interestingly the dll file in AppData\local\Temp is changing each time the project is rebuild. It seems to be a random 8 character string.

For instance If I rebuild the project, the file `wuknqfms.dll`, as in the error message, changes to - `fjcmnzgj.dll`.

On building again it changes to  `imypid1e.dll`. And so on.

More interestingly, older version of Visual Studios such as 2012 and 2010 are working just fine.

I tried troubleblasting this error in following ways -
    1. reinstall Visual Studios
    2. repair Visual Studios
    3. install latest Version of .net
    4. install current msbuild tool
    5. update any updatable package as shown in nuget
    6. Google the issue and look in forums

If you have some lead or suggestion, kindly share.

Comment: 1) Try copying over the project files from VS2012 and let it do any updating of the project (if it calls for it) when you open it. 2) Create a new project and copy block the source code from the old into the new files within your new project.

Comment: I updated project in vs12 to vs13. Error persists. I replaced .vcxproj files from older to newer version. After rebuilding it is showing same error.

Comment: In the project analysis.targets document, some thing is not right in following lines -  <Target Name="SetCABuildNativeEnvironmentVariables">
    <SetEnvironmentVariable Condition="'$(Language)'=='C++' and '$(CAExcludePath)' != ''" EnvValue="$(CAExcludePath)" EnvKey="CAExcludePath"  />
  </Target>

Comment: A couple of other things, try different configurations such as x86 instead of any CPU. Download VS2015 and see what that does for you https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx

Comment: It seems if I comment out the some environment variable in the Microsoft.Code.Analysis.targets xml file, the problem is solved. The line I commented was "<Target Name="SetCABuildNativeEnvironmentVariables">
    <!--<SetEnvironmentVariable Condition="'$(Language)'=='C++' and '$(CAExcludePath)' != ''" EnvValue="$(CAExcludePath)" EnvKey="CAExcludePath"  /> -->
  </Target>"

Answer (score 1):

In your csproj, in the tag <Project>, change the ToolsVersion from 4.0 to 12.0

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873168.aspx

edit: <Project> considered as html tag